# How to read content of an xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have created an XML file and DTD which can be found at the [HERE](http://pastebin.com/SXc0BEUB).

I have written a code, but it works till one level, then it doesnot works properly. I have also created certain objects to store the value of the xml file. But i am only able to traverse till `sheet` tag of the xml, then it doesnot works properly.

```
Recon recon = new Recon();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(configFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root Element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
String outputPath = doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("outputPath");
String withCompareFilePath = doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("withCompareFile");
String toCompareFilePath = doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("toCompareFile");

recon.setOutputPath(outputPath);
recon.setToCompareFile(new File(toCompareFilePath));
recon.setWithCompareFile(new File(withCompareFilePath));

NodeList sheetNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("sheet");

List<ReconSheet> reconSheets = new ArrayList<ReconSheet>();

for(int i = 0; i< sheetNodeList.getLength() ; i++) {
  Node tempNode = sheetNodeList.item(i);
  ReconSheet reconSheet = new ReconSheet();
  NamedNodeMap attMap = tempNode.getAttributes();
  Node sheetNode = attMap.getNamedItem("sheetNumber");
  String sheetNumber = sheetNode.getNodeValue();
  reconSheet.setSheetNumber(Integer.parseInt(sheetNumber));
  NodeList list = tempNode.getChildNodes();
  for(int j = 0; j< list.getLength(); j++) {
    Node inNode = list.item(j);
    System.out.println(inNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: @oers - thanks for doing the much needed edit. M.J, next time please include your code samples in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could map your XML directly to your domain model using a JAXB implementation.  JAXB requires Java SE 5, and a JAXB implementation is included in Java SE 6.

**Recon**

Your `Recon` class would look something like:

```
package forum7673323;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Recon {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String outputPath;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FileAdapter.class)
    private File withCompareFile;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FileAdapter.class)
    private File toCompareFile;

    @XmlElement(name="sheet")
    private List<ReconSheet> reconSheets;

}
```

**ReconSheet**

```
package forum7673323;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ReconSheet {

    @XmlAttribute
    int sheetNumber;
}
```

**FileAdapter**

Since a JAXB implementation can not interact with a `java.io.File` object directly we will use a JAXB adapter to handle this conversion.  The use of this adapter is specified on the `Recon` class using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```
package forum7673323;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class FileAdapter extends XmlAdapter <String, File>{

    @Override
    public String marshal(File file) throws Exception {
        if(null == file) {
            return null;
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    @Override
    public File unmarshal(String path) throws Exception {
        return new File(path);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum7673323;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Recon.class);

        File xml = new File("src/forum7673323/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Recon recon = (Recon) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(recon, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recon toCompareFile="h:\work\two.xls" withCompareFile="h:\work\one.xls" outputPath="h:/work">
    <sheet sheetNumber="1"/>
</recon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but isn't the `getAttributes()` method responsible for bringing the attibutes of the tag rather than sub-elements?

Comment: have u checked the link which contains the XML file, in that i also need to read the attribute from the XML that is why i used the `getAttribute()` method.